# Is there a way to find out how many comments and questions you have sent

Tags: support, questions, comments, deleted-questions, user-profiles

Just out of interest I would like to find out how many comments and questions I have sent over my time on "Super User". I would like to know this because of some results to do with badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all this from [your profile](https://superuser.com/users/465600/racing121?tab=topactivity). Click the different tabs to see how many answers, questions, edits, comments, etc. you've made. For example, to see the number of comments, click "all actions" and then "[comments](https://superuser.com/users/465600/racing121?tab=activity&sort=comments)".

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helped